# creat a class in pyhton - pooling REST (json responses) to log in a CSV

Tags: python, json, rest

Need to creat a class which is pooling REST (json responses). After that I need to save them in a CSV-File.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to write classes in Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Here's how to make requests:
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

And here's how to write to CSV files using Python:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html